# css text scroller marquee alternative

Tags: javascript, css, marquee

I have a pretty small div class that I have a standard Marquee in but it is old stuff and doesnt work well on all devices. I have looked and tried several but they seem to mess the whole page up.

I basically need it to display text only consisting of say 7 lines of text and after few seconds, load the next set of 7 lines with te option of horizontal or vertically. Not really fussed about how glam it looks it just has to fit. It would be nice if it moved them all in one go but no fussed just trying to make it work. Its in bootstrap.

Any examples or help would be appreciated.

Jules

Comment: Please include your HTML section.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].